# JOGL: Black panel on windows

Tags: windows, jogl

I have a class that extends a GLJPanel and has a `GLEventListener` with

```
    @Override
    public void display( GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable ) {
        System.out.println("Painting");
        if(image!=null){
            GL2 gl2 = glautodrawable.getGL().getGL2();
            int format = GL.GL_LUMINANCE;
            int type  = GL.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT;
            DataBufferUShort db = (DataBufferUShort) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
            short[] shorts = db.getData(0);
            Buffer buffer = ShortBuffer.wrap(shorts);
            gl2.glDrawPixels(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), format , type, buffer );
        }
    }
```

On Linux the image is displayed as I expect and the display method is called. On Windows the same code displays a black screen and it doesn't look like it calls the display method. The gears demo runs no problem on the Windows system.

EDIT:

I have narrowed it down to issues with GridBagLayout. Setting the `gbc.anchor` equal to `LINE_START`, `LINE_END` and `CENTER` is causing the image to appear or not

```
int bitdepth = 10;
                    GLProfile.initSingleton();
                    GLProfile glProfile = GLProfile.getDefault();

                    GLCapabilities glCapabilities = new GLCapabilities( glProfile );
                    glCapabilities.setBlueBits(bitdepth);
                    glCapabilities.setGreenBits(bitdepth);
                    glCapabilities.setRedBits(bitdepth);
                    glCapabilities.setAlphaBits(2);
                    glCapabilities.setDoubleBuffered(true);
                    glCapabilities.setHardwareAccelerated(true);
                    glCapabilities.setNumSamples(4);
                    glCapabilities.setBackgroundOpaque(false);
                    glCapabilities.setSampleBuffers(true);
                    GraphicsConfiguration gc = DeviceController.getConfOfRightMostMonitorAndLargest();




                    JFrame jf = new JFrame(gc);
                    jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

                    GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(glCapabilities);
                    canvas.addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
                                int arg4) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
                            System.out.println("Painting");



                            BufferedImage image = null;
                            try {
                                image = ImageIO.read(new File("img.tiff"));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if(image!=null){
                                GL2 gl2 = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

                                //gl2.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                                int format = GL.GL_LUMINANCE;
                                int type  = GL.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT;

                                DataBufferUShort db = (DataBufferUShort) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
                                short[] shorts = db.getData(0);
                                Buffer buffer = ShortBuffer.wrap(shorts);
                                //gl2.glViewport(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

                                gl2.glDrawPixels(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), format , type, buffer );

                            }

                        }
                    });




                    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
                    jp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                    gbc.gridx=0;
                    gbc.gridy=0;
                    gbc.gridwidth=1;
                    gbc.gridheight=1;
                    gbc.weightx=1;
                    gbc.weighty=1;
                    gbc.anchor= GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
                    jp.add(canvas,gbc);

                    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();
                    jsp.getViewport().add(jp);

                    JLayeredPane jlp = new JLayeredPane();
                    jlp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                    jlp.add(jsp, gbc);

                    //jsp.getViewport().add(dsc);
                    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc.gridx=0;
                    gbc.gridy=0;
                    gbc.gridwidth=1;
                    gbc.gridheight=1;
                    gbc.weightx=1;
                    gbc.weighty=1;
                    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                    gbc.anchor= GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
                    jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    jf.getContentPane().add(jlp,gbc);

                    jf.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please provide a COMPLETE example. The culprit is probably elsewhere. Use the debug mode. Maybe your image isn't found under Windows.

Comment: @gouessej I am trying to transition a large project from Swing to JOGL. The image is certainly there and not null but the odd thing is that the display method is never called. It never prints out "Painting". I will create a SSCE today.

Comment: Have you tried to run a rudimentary example like this one? https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98

Comment: @gouessej I am trying to reproduce my issue by pulling the application apart. I have gotten some simple examples running but I have run into other issues with GLJPanel and GLCanvas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951981/glcanvas-and-gljpanel-not-identical

Comment: You should contact us on our official forum as your questions are very specific to JOGL: http://forum.jogamp.org

Comment: @goussej I have posted on the forum